# Jquery getting the html from specific class within a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table and I wish to extract the html from a specific row without a specific class.

So for example with the row:

```
<tr>
<th class='a'></th>
<th class='b'></th>
<th class='c'></th>
<tr>
```

I would hope to get a result like

```
<th class='b'></th>
<th class='c'></th>
```

I've attempted a few variants of

```
var newTr = $('#table01 tr:nth-child(2) .a').remove().html();
```

But it's not returning the desired result and it's removing the th's from the original rows(as expected I guess)

Would it be best to use a regex to strip the content out or is there a jQuery selector I can use?

Comment: you want to  return content  with out removing?

Comment: Are you trying to return the contents of the <th> with the class "a"? I.e. from <th class="a">ASDF</a> you would want ASDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting the HTML of the row, you need to point jQuery to the `<tr>` for `.html()` while `.remove()` would still need it to point to the `<th>`.

However, after `.remove()`, you won't be able to simply traverse from `<th>` to `<tr>` as they won't be related (e.g., via `.parent()`). To get around this, you can use a series of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to point to the `<th>` just long enough for `.remove`:

```
$('#table01 tr:nth-child(2)').
    find('.a').remove().end().
    html();
```

- jQuery begins with the `<tr>` w/ `:nth-child(2)`
- `.find()` will move to the `<th class="a">`, which you `.remove()`
- `.end()` will return to the `<tr>`, to grab the remaining `.html()`

Also, if you don't actually want to affect the table -- just the result -- toss in a `.clone()`:

```
$('#table01 tr:nth-child(2)').clone().
    find('.a').remove().end().
    html();
```

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)'s manual

Answer (score 0):

```
var ths = $('#table01 tr:nth-child(2) th').not('.a').clone().html();
```

Maybe something like that. It's hard to answer on an iPod touch.